# Can't Start Django-Tailwind in Dev Mode

Tags: django, tailwind-css

I am working with django-tailwind on Windows and am following the steps to install. The current step is to 'start tailwind in dev mode' using `python manage.py tailwind start`. This always fails and the following block of text is the resulting log file:

```
...
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle django_tailwind@~prestart: django_tailwind@
6 info lifecycle django_tailwind@~start: django_tailwind@
7 verbose lifecycle django_tailwind@~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle django_tailwind@~start: PATH: C:\Users\jpyth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;c:\Users\jpyth\Django\hhs-robotics-website\theme\static_src\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\jpyth\Django\hhs-robotics-website\venv\Scripts;C:\ActiveTcl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\jpyth\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\jpyth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\GCL-2.6.1\bin\;C:\ccl\launcher;C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\bin;C:\opencv\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg\;C:\Users\jpyth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\ActiveTcl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\jpyth\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\jpyth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\GCL-2.6.1\bin\;C:\ccl\launcher;C:;C:\Users\jpyth\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle django_tailwind@~start: CWD: c:\Users\jpyth\Django\hhs-robotics-website\theme\static_src
10 silly lifecycle django_tailwind@~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', "watch 'npm run build-postcss' ./src" ]
11 silly lifecycle django_tailwind@~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle django_tailwind@~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: django_tailwind@ start: `watch 'npm run build-postcss' ./src`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jpyth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jpyth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid django_tailwind@
15 verbose cwd c:\Users\jpyth\Django\hhs-robotics-website\theme\static_src
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\jpyth\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v12.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.7.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error django_tailwind@ start: `watch 'npm run build-postcss' ./src`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the django_tailwind@ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

One thing I noticed is that the command that it is failing on uses `watch`, which is not a Windows command. However, I did try running the input to `watch` (`npm run build-postcss`) but to no avail. I even created a custom `watch.bat` script which I added to PATH and it still fails. I have no clue where to go from here. How can I get tailwind css to work in my Django app?

Comment: Jesse did you get a solution for this , if so mind sharing it i ran into the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry this came late faced the same  thing just yesterday and came across your question but here's the fix since we are using windows we have to change
the qoutes we use so 
within ./theme/static_src/package.json change 
`"start": "watch 'npm run build-postcss' ./src"`

to

```
"start": "watch \"npm run build-postcss\" ./src"
```

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you, Jordan.

Answer (score 1):

Since there was a change on **May 14 2020** in package.json that changed the start command, the answer above no longer works. ([see the change here](https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind/commit/cbaa22e01ec3d10be0f3a5a5de1f98595d87bd5e#diff-b5950d3ab6f62eb22f2cd61dff67aa3b))
Because of this another problem arose. To solve this you have to change the following in theme/static_src/package.json:

```
"dev": "watch 'npm run dev:sass && npm run dev:postcss' ./src",
```

to

```
"dev": "watch \"npm run dev:sass && npm run dev:postcss\" ./src",
```

Hope this helps!