# npm start in dev mode within django project fail using django-tailwind package

Tags: django, npm, windows-10, tailwind-css, python-3.8

im trying to use the below package to use tailwind css within my django project im using a windows 10 machine 
[package used to integrate tailwind-css in django](https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind)

tailwind-css uses npm modules to install and start of which the install worked although the start failed giving me the below error (all steps in the package Readme were followed upto 7 where the error occured)

[image]

im trying to figure out whether its an issue nodejs has with windows or not. any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you're watching this after May 14 2020 see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784555/cant-start-django-tailwind-in-dev-mode/62682535#62682535) thread!

Answer (score 1):

here's the fix since we are using windows we have to change the qoutes we use so within ./theme/static_src/package.json change `"start": "watch 'npm run build-postcss' ./src"`

to

`"start": "watch \"npm run build-postcss\" ./src"`

Comment: it solves the error, but it starts but stops at this line `postcss --config . --map false --output ../static/css/styles.min.css ./src/styles.scss`. Did you get this up and running?